# What is the difference between Breath of the Wild's Thunderblade and Frostblade?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I recently noticed something similar with the thunderblade and frostblade: they both stop enemies from moving. While the thunderblade stuns, the frostblade freezes. However, is there any other major difference between the 2 weapons that **isn't** obvious such as damage, stun/freeze time, etc ? I still don't have either weapon so I can't test it for myself.

Note that the obvious means like how frostblade works better in hot areas such as Death Mountain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like Ben said, the only difference between the two weapons is that one provides a frost modifier, and the other provides a shock modifier. There is no other difference between the weapons. This frost/shock modifier, however, has multiple effects. Ben has gone through the direct effects from these modifiers, so I wll go through the other effects.

Effects from frost modifier:

- Instantly kills fire-based enemies (Fire/Meteo Wizzrobes, Fire-Breath Lizalfos, and Fire Chuchu)
- [Decreases the ambient temperature around you](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Frostblade), which indirectly provides heat resistance in hot areas like Gerudo Desert (it also indirectly provides fire resistance for Death Mountain, but it must be combined with another source of fire resistance to avoid the burning point)
- Can freeze cooking ingredients
- Changes Chuchu Jelly to White Chuchu Jelly

Effects from shock modifier:

- [Increased power (and shock effect) during rainy weather](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderblade)
- [Can activate the shock effect around it when the item is dropped midswing and then drop a conductive item which touches it.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/8cvcqn/how_to_make_a_battery_with_a_thunderblade/) [Rain make this more potent.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/8myutv/rain_thunderblade_effortless_remote_kills/)
- Changes Chuchu Jelly to Yellow Chuchu Jelly

Comment: Death Mountain is a bad example because an ice weapon isn't enough to lower temperature below the burning point. Ice weapons are great for traversing Gerudo Desert though.

Comment: Death mountain needs 2 items of heat resistance to avoid burning point. Ice weapons indirectly lower it by one, which is identical to the benefit of one piece of heat-resistant clothing. It is still helpful, just not self-sufficient.

Comment: Your last link is broken.

Comment: What about the fire ChuChu? It also one shots them, right? Plus I've seen some times where if you even get near a fire ChuChu, it looks like it cools down, turning from bright redish orange to almost blackish brown.

Comment: Doesn't death mountain specifically need *fire* resistance, not heat resistance?

Comment: Yes it’s fire resistance, but I still found myself only needing one item of fire resistance instead of two when holding a frost weapon. Good pick up on the heat resistance part; I can change the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 15):

Thunderblade stuns enemies, Frostblade freezes. While they both stop an enemy, that's really where the similarities end.

Frozen enemies will be critical hit on their next hit, which will cause them to ragdoll and thaw.

Contrast this with stunned enemies, which remain stunned even if you hit them again. Also, no critical hit is given.

You could conclude that the Frostblade is a more powerful weapon due to its guaranteed critical hit, but because the enemy thaws, you could lose them if you hit them off a hill

Needless to say, there are many differences between using the Thunderblade and the Frostblade

Comment: What about damage? Which has more damage?

Comment: As far as I know they both do the base damage of their respective weapon and nothing more @Bloonchipper

Comment: So both have the same damage?

Comment: @Bloonchipper I believe that the damage is based on the base given. I don't think that it will always be the same, even between 2 of the same type. Then again, it has been a while since I have played, and I didn't often use those weapons.

Comment: @Ben It might be important to note that Frozen enemies can unthaw after a time period (I can't remember what this time period is off the top of my head), which is much longer than stunned enemies

Comment: Though frozen enemies remain frozen longer than stunned enemies, the stunned duration is often still long enough to land multiple additional attacks on the enemy, whereas getting more than one additonal attack on frozen enemies is much harder since they thaw and ragdoll. I normally prefer the Thunderblade because of this.

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind is that Electric enemies are resistant to thunder and Ice enemies are resistant to ice. Also, ice one-shots Fire enemies. I'm not aware of any enemy having a thunder weakness (unless you count Vah Ruta).

Comment: And thunderblade emits electricity if you place it near metal. That way you may enable switches or build traps.